# req.body.username not outputting the correct value

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

sent data -
http.send(JSON.stringify(data));

outputting data -> {username: "dsa", password: "dsa"}

outputting JSON.stringify(data) ->
"{"username":"dsa","password":"dsa"}"

outputting req.body server side ->
{ '{"username":"dsa","password":"dsa"}': '' }

outputting req.body.username ->
undefined (expecting "dsa")

Body parser is installed and used with the app.

Javascript:

```
server.register = function(){
    console.log('ran func');
    usernameinput = document.getElementById("registerform").elements["username"].value
    passwordinput = document.getElementById("registerform").elements["password"].value
    var data = {
        "username":usernameinput,
        "password":passwordinput
    }
    http.open("post", server.regurl,true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.send(JSON.stringify(data));

}
```

server setup code contains the following:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/')),
```

Comment: try req.username, I don't see any "body" property in your JSON.

Comment: @James also undefined

Comment: where did you declare or import http . htpp module  only  avaliable in server side .

Comment: I have const http = new XMLHttpRequest(); in my javascript file and http = require('http').Server(app) in my server file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stringified your JSON object so you can really adress its keys on server side - Its a plain string.

you could send it as is (a JSON object)

`sent data - http.send(data);`

or

`sent data - http.send({payload: JSON.stringify(data)});`

and then on server side

```
var x = JSON.parse(req.body.payload)
x.username;
```

***UPDATE FOR ANSWER:***

after reading a bit. 
[AJAX - Send a Request To a Server](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

and it says you should infact send a 
string so it might be just a bad string format.

```
xhttp.open("POST", "demo_post2.asp", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
```

but JSON.stringify won't give you this 'URLish' syntax. maybe you should manipulate the string before you send it .

Comment: var x = JSON.parse(req.body); is giving me a TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: how are you sending the params? from where. please add some description to your question. If you use app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
` Then it's all set . you need to send params in HTTP request. but i do not know how you implement send.. please elaborate for further assistance.

Comment: the reason this is happaning to you is because req.body is already an object so you cant really parse it to anything. i guess you're problem is in how you try to make the request if you post it we can see the whole procces and fix it

Comment: Added more details to question @FedeSc

Comment: and if you just send data without stringify to server? you should be able to just reach `req.body.username` ..

Comment: console.log(req.body.username); results in undefined, with var data = {
        "username":usernameinput,
        "password":passwordinput
    } and http.send(data);

Comment: This worked - with var parameters = "username="+usernameinput+"&password="+passwordinput and http.send(parameters);       Thanks alot for your help @FedeSc

Comment: Glad i could help. Keep on coding! ✌

Answer (score 1):

if you are using JSON.stringify you need something like this 'application/json'

```
server.register = function(){
    console.log('ran func');
    usernameinput = document.getElementById("registerform").elements["username"].value
    passwordinput = document.getElementById("registerform").elements["password"].value
    var data = {
        "username":usernameinput,
        "password":passwordinput
    }
    http.open("post", server.regurl,true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
    http.send(JSON.stringify(data));

}
```